# Rails 5 assets return 404 in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I know this question is asked a lot, but I'm losing my mind here.  I started building an app using Rails 5.  I deployed to AWS EB and set the env to development.  But my assets aren't loading.  Getting a 404.  I implemented sprockets and `require 'rails/all'` in my application.rb file as well as running `rake assets:precompile`.  I also tried all the `config.asset` configurations in development.rb:

```
config.assets_compile
config.public_file_server.enabled
config.assets.digest
config.assets.enabled
```

My nginx error log is full of the following for each of my assets.  The path is wrong.  I didn't put my assets in `/var/app/current/public`, I put them in `/var/app/current/app/assets`.  At some point, I had it fetching from there (don't remember how) but it still didn't work:

```
2017/07/28 01:16:15 [error] 2994#0: *1387 open() "/var/app/current/public/assets/merck-logo.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 76.218.103.88, server: _, request: "GET /assets/merck-logo.png HTTP/1.1", host: "merckcoupons-dev1.dv3ww3wmii.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://merckcoupons-dev1.dv3ww3wmii.us-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/circular"
```

The crazy thing is that I just did this with another app not too long ago and have it open as a guide.  I've been googling for hours and I can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the following https://hackernoon.com/how-to-setup-and-deploy-a-rails-5-app-on-aws-beanstalk-with-postgresql-redis-and-more-88a38355f1ea
You can also look at the official AWS documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Comment: @StephanePaquet.  Thanks, I have

Comment: typically you would deploy using `production` or `staging` env, not `development`. you need to precompile the assets (this will make fingerprinted copies of the files in the public directory), `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile
`  please review the rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: @house9 I followed your advice and used test.  I ran `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV` but it only compiled the css and js, so thats working.  No images though

Comment: How are you referencing those images?  for example, where is "merck-logo.png" being referenced?

Comment: @BrandonElder here's an example: `<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/ClubGanadero.png"), circular_path %>`

Comment: hmm..  and your `production.rb` has `config.assets.compile = true` ?

Comment: @BrandonElder, Yes, it does. So does test.rb, which is what I am using for this instance.  I also added `config.assets.precompile += %w[*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif]`, clobbered my assets, precompiled, noticed it does in fact precompile images, commited and deploy.  Still not working.  Could it be something about the fingerprint mapping?

Comment: It might be something to do with the static assets since it seems to be only the images that aren't loading.  I really don't know.  Mayyybe you can try changing the line in `production.rb` from `config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` to `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` .

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: Figure this out yet?  After thinking about this more, I'm pretty convinced that this is a Nginx configuration issue.  Hard to say without seeing your nginx settings (and I'm no expert) but that's where I would look at this point.

Comment: Hard to answer without your environment.rb file, production.rb and development.rb files and nginx config.

Comment: do NOT use `test` environment unless you are running specs/tests, it deletes all of the data from your database typically during each run. Unless you mean you used `test` during just the asset pre-compilation? Typically the best thing to do is copy `environments/production` to `environments/staging` and add a staging entry to `database.yml` for non production deployed environments

Comment: NOTE: `<%= image_tag("/assets/ClubGanadero.png") %>` is not correct, the `image_tag` is aware of the asset pipeline, use: `<%= image_tag("ClubGanadero.png") %>`, which should pull from `app/assets/images` in development mode and pull from `public/assets/PROPER_FINGERPRINTED_FILE` in other environments (where precompiled)

Comment: @house9  Just curious...  will using `<%= image_tag("/assets/ClubGanadero.png") %>` absolutely not work in this case, or is it just not the correct way?  I had it in my head that either would work but I'm sure you're right.

Comment: I think it will work if you have the file on your server: `/public/assets/ClubGanadero.png`, I can't remember if asset compilation creates that file, usually it creates one with a fingerprint in the file name only.

Comment: To confirm this is not an nginx issue, look at the files on your server created by the precompile: `public/assets/XXXX.png` and try to bring that up in a browser directly instead of via rails view, i.e. http://your-domain/assets/XXXX.png

Comment: @house9 was correct!  The image_tag line was incorrect!  Thank everyone.  house9, do you want to do the honor of posting the answer?

Comment: Glad you got it solved.  I'm relatively new to RoR and have struggled at times with the asset pipeline.  often it's been very obvious and simple changes that needed to be made.

Comment: The asset pipeline is super powerful, but a bit of a nightmare at the same time. One of the areas of rails where the magic is hard to understand.

Comment: @BrandonElder it's amazing how often its jsut a simple change.  Programming can be so pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When referencing images using the `image_tag` helper only include the filename and no path. Rails will use the file in `app/assets/images` in development environment and then use `public/assets/IMAGE_NAME_FINGER_PRINT.ext` in other environments (after pre-compilation)

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

For example:

GOOD: `<%= image_tag 'rails.png' %>`

BAD: `<%= image_tag '/assets/rails.png' %>`